# Numpy: return boolean array after condition checking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, conditional-statements

Simple question: I know that stuff like

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2])
(a < 2)
```

will return a boolean array where the condition (elem < 2) was checked:

```
array([True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Is this a native numpy method? I searched for the documentation of this but were not able to find any :(

Can someone supply a link for the documentation?

Is something like `(a < 2).sum()` considered "good style" for counting the amount of elements which fulfill a certain condition?

...and finally: are there faster ways for turning an array to a boolean array based on a condition? Or is this already an efficient way for checking each element against a condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would be concerned about speed or a better way.

Think about addition:

```
a + 1
```

that adds `1` to each element of `a`, right?  Why not perform a conditional test in the same way - test each element.

This similar to the list comprehension, only done in faster compiled code

```
[i+1 for i in a]
[i<2 for i in a]
```

`(a < 2).sum()` works because `True/False` are treated the same as `1/0`.  It too has to iterate through all the elements of the boolean, summing them.

Syntatically, expressions like `a+1` and `a<2` are transoformed into calls, `a.__add__(1)`, `a.__lt__(2)`.  Those functions in turn are created from compiled code.  The numpy source code is available on `github` but is not easy to follow.

Perhaps the most relevant doc section is

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations

(though mostly it just lists the equivalence between array methods and syntactic expressions, much as I did.)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. One question left: is this native numpy functionality? If so: where to find the documentation?

Comment: What do you mean by `native numpy functionality`?  Somethings are done by the Python interpreter, some by `numpy` functions, mostly methods of the `ndarray` object.

Comment: I thought of whether this is a common python syntax which I did not know or if this is a function implemented in numpy or even a direct method of every ndarray object.

Comment: this is not providing the expected solution to the question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is native.

```
In [5]: a=random(1e7)

In [6]: %timeit  a < .5 
10 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop

In [8]: 33e-3/len(a)
Out[8]: 3.3e-09
```

This show that each comparison cost about 3 ns, what is impossible with python ints.

for count, `count_nonzero(a<2)` is faster and more natural.